# Update without where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

```
+------+------+
| id   | no   |
+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |
|   11 |    1 |
|   21 |    1 |
+------+------+
```

I want to update 2nd row no. to 2. 
the query i can use is

```
update test set no = 2 where id = 11;
```

How can i achieve the same without where clause ??

Comment: Ask yourself this question: _why_ do you not want to use a `where` clause? I suspect there is more behind your question than what you wrote. Probably the real issue you have is something else which you believe you can solve by not using such clause. But that only makes it hard for us to help. So simply explain your issue, not how you want to solve it. I suspect you are looking for some other, implicit means to identify the row to receive the update, not it's ID...

Comment: All the "answers" below just disguise the where clause into something less readable.

Comment: @arkascha: some of these techniques can be used to exploit SQL Injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: @arkascha . . . That is not true.  The solutions below using `case` or `if` may perform *much* worse than the version using the `where`, especially when there is an index on `id` (which would be expected).  Even without an index, MySQL incurs overhead for noticing that an update is *not* necessary for a given row, although the overhead is less because MySQL then ignores the update.

Comment: @spencer7593 So? Looking for vulnerabilities is part of the daily work for a developer. If that is the issue, then I would expect the OP to ask about it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I never said the disguise does not have any impact on performance. If you disguise yourself as a ghost and wear bedsheets and a heavy chain you will probably take more time for your 100m sprint. Nevertheless that will be called a disguise :-)

Comment: @arkascha This exact question is asked in an exam, as a challenging question only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To update the "second" row in the table, the row that has the second smallest id value...

```
UPDATE test t
  JOIN ( SELECT r.id
           FROM test r
          ORDER BY r.id 
          LIMIT 1,1
       ) s
    ON s.id = t.id
   SET t.no = 2
```

**EDIT**

As a followup to clarify the results of the query above...

In the case where `id` is not unique in the table, the query could potentially update *more than one* row. The inline view query (`s`) gets the id value from the "second" row, after the rows are ordered by id value. Then *all* rows that have that same id value would be updated.

This is an issue only if `id` is *not* unique; if `id` is unique, the statement would update (at most) one row.

For example, if the contents of the table was:

```
+-----+-----+
| id  | no  |
+-----+-----+
|   1 |   1 |
|  11 |   3 | <-- "second" row, ordered by id ascending 
|  11 |   4 | <-- id from third row matches id from second row
|  21 |   1 |
+-----+-----+
```

The result of the query above would be to update the *two* rows that have `id` value of `11`.

```
+-----+-----+
| id  | no  |
+-----+-----+
|   1 |   1 |
|  11 |   2 |  <-- updated
|  11 |   2 |  <-- updated
|  21 |   1 |
+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure **why** you would want to but...

```
UPDATE `test` SET `no` = IF(`id`=11, 1, `no`);
```

For the record, I would be surprised if this didn't perform horribly as it would go through every row in the table.

Comment: I think you mean "not" surprised .. ;)  but yeah, that'll work - it's not advisable, but it does answer his question. O.o

Comment: Haha, yeah, NOT surprised. (Edited)

Answer (score 1):

That´s not possible, a update without where is an update to all the table. You can try this, but it is always like a where:

```
update test set no = case id when 11 then 2 else no end
```

Answer (score 1):

And yet a 3rd way...

```
update test A INNER JOIN test B 
  on A.ID = B.ID 
 and B.ID = 11
 set A.No = 2;
```

For clarity this does a self join on a table that only has record 11, thus updating only record 11 (b.iD = 11). using an ON Clause.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't use a `where` clause and it might be a bit faster than using `if()` or `case`:

```
update test t join
       (select 1 as dum) dum
       on t.id = 11
    set t.no = 2 ;
```