# Convert INSERT INTO into UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Imagine I have some code like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tablename (column1, column2, column3) VALUES 
('1','2','3')";
```

How would I convert this into an UPDATE query? I did some searching, but

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,... 
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

doesn't make much sense to me. Thanks

Comment: isn't that sql structure incorrect

Comment: why you want to replace this insert query into update ? If I am not wrong, you have condition of inserting and updating records on the basis of condition right ?

Comment: Sorry. Fixed it @MASIDDIQUI

Comment: I have this code that inserts values into a table when a user creates an account. However, if they want to change their details later, I assume it will require an UPDATE query, right? @rahul_m

Comment: UPDATE tablex
SET name='xxx', 
WHERE id=1; go like this...

Comment: @Caspar It is the way to go, why don't it make sense to you?

Comment: @Linkan I'm just confused with the UPDATE syntax, that's all. Looking at these comments, to update the value of column 1, 2 and 3 to the values 1,2 and 3 accordingly I assume I would do this, correct me if I am wrong: $sql = UPDATE tablename SET column1=1,column2=2,column3=3;

Comment: @Sona I'm just confused with the UPDATE syntax, that's all. Looking at these comments, to update the value of column 1, 2 and 3 to the values 1,2 and 3 accordingly I assume I would do this, correct me if I am wrong: $sql = UPDATE tablename SET column1=1,column2=2,column3=3;

Comment: @Caspar i have given example that is not exactly answer for your question... i will update.

Comment: UPDATE tablename SET column1='1',column2='2',column3='3' WHERE id=1; go like this

Comment: This question is NOT at all a duplicate of the stated duplicate.  Entirely different question.  Granted, the question could have been written in much more clear way.

Answer (score 2):

**INSERT** and **UPDATE** queries look similar but they do different things.

Inserts => Inserts new **nonexisting** data into table

Update => Updates **existing** data inside of the table

That is why the **UPDATE** query has **WHERE** clause

So, you can use **UPDATE** to modify a row which is already inserted.

Comment: I'm just confused with the UPDATE syntax, that's all. Looking at these comments, to update the value of column 1, 2 and 3 to the values 1,2 and 3 according I assume I would do this, correct me if I am wrong:

        $sql = UPDATE tablename SET column1=1,column2=2,column3=3;

Comment: Yes what you are doing is correct. However do not forget about WHERE clause because you can not update nonexisting DATA.

Comment: @Caspar `update` needs `where` clause or some other ways(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30198070/) to update an existing row. But other ways are generally slow by performance

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you are asking, because you are not clear in your question. But according to my thinking you want to know the difference.

**Update** query edit or update the data in the database. Like this

```
update table_name
set 'name'=something
where 'id'='some_id'
```

for more examples and practice go [HERE](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp)

**Insert** insert query is just making a new data entry in the database in a table with a unique id, precisely.

[HERE](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp) is the link for insert example.